# Three20/TTStyle.h No such file or directory error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, header-files

I have project, this contains header files like.

```
#import "Three20/TTButton.h"
#import "Three20/TTStyle.h"
#import "Three20/TTStyleSheet.h"
#import "Three20/TTView.h"
#import "Three20/TTShape.h"
```

but i am getting no such file, directory error.
But i can see those TTButton.h,TTStyle.h... are inside the Three20 Folder.

Please Help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these instructions to the letter:

http://three20.info/setup/existing

Most importantly:

> Finally, we need to tell your project
>   where to find the Three20 headers.
>   Open your "Project Settings" and go to
>   the "Build" tab. Be sure to select the
>   appropriate active configuration (eg,
>   Release vs. Debug -- eventually you'll
>   need to change both). Look for "Header
>   Search Paths" and double-click it. Add
>   the relative path from your project's
>   directory to the "Three20/src"
>   directory. If your project and the
>   Three20 source are in the same parent,
>   you would enter "../Three20/src".

Comment: Thank you very much Jasarien, the link you provided solved my problem,
thanks again.

Comment: If my answer helped, then you should mark it as accepted. The same applies to your other questions. If you don't mark answers as accepted, you'll be depriving the community of its reputation which is meant as a reward for providing their time to help you out.

Comment: > +1, I have faced the same problem, and i donno how to give the header search path. I kept the project folder and downloaded file is in my desktop. I gave "../Three20/src" to header search path, it shown the error is "error: Three20/Three20.h: No such file or directory". So please help me out. Thanks.